# Preventing cache overflow

Tags: php

At the moment I'm working on a system that caches dynamically created files, nothing too new there. Basically how it works is that it will go through the $_GET array and will create a directory structure based on querystring variables. Off course it's a little more secure than that, but you get the picture.

The problem with this is that anyone could surf to for example:

> www.example.com/?page=foo&page2=bar (which would generate /cachefiles/foo/bar.html)

and change the page2 value randomly each time, thus creating a new cachefile.
So someone could just make 10000 requests with random querystrings and there would be new cachefiles generated for each and every single one of them.

An extra problem is that I actually want to allow this in a way, as it' will be part of a CMS which people should be able to write plugins for and thus use their own querystring variables. As the querystrings are usually vital to the content of the page, there should be a new chachefile for different querystrings.

So basically I want to allow the use of querystrings in this context, but prevent abuse of them.

To me it sounds rather impossible to have one but not the other, but as I'm no guru I'm hoping some of you could perhaps share your thoughts on this and adice on best practises (and / or alternative methods).

I do know there's a few cache libraries out there, but I prefer to do things on my own so I understand what's going on and how stuff works.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your replies everyone. I think I will try to combine some of your suggestions into one system. So I will add the functionality for plugin developers to register their querystring variables into the API, as well as do some more profound checks. However, please consider following scenario:

User requests a static page, but in the template of it a plugin-calendar is loaded: eg. example.com/?page1=static&calenderStartmonth=5
Here's the root of the problem: calendarStartMonth can be one of 12 and does need to be able to change, so caching would need to re-occur every time calendarStartMonth changes. If the plugin developer does not check the input, and someone uses a random nr for 10000 requests, that would overflow the cache, would it not? Off course I realise it's not very effective to cache the page again everytime the calenderMonth changes, that's why I asked for some best practice advice. Would I have to come up with a system which caches all but the plugins?  Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: why cant you do a check that the page exists before creating a cached version of it, or make it so if the page dont exist then only have 1 cached 404 page

Comment: So, in one sentence, you're trying to prevent flood abuse of your caching mechanism?

Comment: That's correct, although there's some specifics to this case I couldn't fit into one sentence ;).

Comment: @nwm: I answered it in my answer. Just check the value if they are out of range. it's pretty simple `if ($_GET['calendarStartmonth']>12) exit;`

Comment: Hi yes123 - thanks for your replies. My issue is though that I don't control the plugins, so I can't control their querystring input, unless plugin developers would be able to tell me how to do so, bt then they could forget. However, I could make it obligatory for a plugin developer to hand the cache engine the info I suppose. I'll have a think about it, but again, thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @NwN: Ok. if it was helpful to you think to pick it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you write some small API to let the CMS and the plugin developers register pages in the database they are going to create (read: allow).

This way you also solve the problem of cache-flushing as you really know what is about to be deleted and when.

Comment: This to me seems the most feasable answer so far. If I understand correctly you would have the plugin developer register his querystring variables in some way or another so that the cache engine knows which ones to allow and which values to accept?

Comment: Yes. I can't speak about your page concept but the basic idea is that you get a means to _really_ know on the server side (a) what is a cachable object and (b) to find the objects and remove them. Combined with metadata (who/when/what ...) it's easy to remove (flush) cached objects or get a current status view in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

To prvent abuse you need to add an extra checks before you start your cache engine.

Something that checks `$_GET keys and values` and if something isn't good it prints a `die('Error');`

You can use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to check if acutally the `$_GET` keys are only that allowed.

Also I suggest you to do not create folder based on the $_GET params.

You should set a base dir of your cache, example `/var/www/myCache/` and then you create your cache file with

```
$cacheBaseDir .= sha1($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This is what i do in my CMS actually.

Of course you could expand this behaviour if you are worried about too many files cache in only one directory (this could be cause of some performance problem on older machine)

You can actually spread your caches file based on first chars of the `sha1();`

So you would do something like:

```
$hash = sha1($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);    
$finalCacheDir = $cacheBaseDir . substr($hash,0,2) . '/' . $hash;
```

This way your cache files will spreads on about `256` sub directories.

Comment: This is how i would do it too `http://lcherone.blogspot.com/2011/05/simple-php-cache-class.html`

Comment: @Lawrence: Thanks for not making that link clickable >.<

Comment: lol where did you find that `≉` it deserves +1. Anyway why 16? isn't that ~30^2 ? `substr($hash,0,2)` Example: `a9`, `3z` etc.

Comment: @yes123: `sha1` returns a hexadecimal value in default mode.

Comment: @gumbo: wops I always thought it used all [a-z] fixed anyway. Dunno why it doesn't

Comment: @yes123: In that case it would be 36^2.

Answer (score 0):

Do a check for the page before serving it, and if it does not exist, do something similar to this:

```
if (!$page_exists) {
   header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
   die("<h1>404 Not Found</h1>\nThe page that you have requested could not be found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash value across your parameters and append it to the query string. Only cache the pages if the passed paramaters match your query string.

e.g.

```
$vars= array('hello'=>'world','second'=>'value');
$vars['hash'] = md5('MySecret' . serialize($vars));

foreach($vars as $k=>$v){
    $out[] = $k .'='. $v;
}

$link = 'index.php?' . implode('&amp;',$out);
```

On the receiving side:

```
$vars = $_GET;
$hashUrl = $vars['hash'];
unset($vars['hash']);

if(md5('MySecret' . serialize($vars)) == $hashUrl){
    // cache the page and proceed
}else{
    // someone fiddled with the parameters
}
```

(This obviosly doesn't excuse you from checking the values in a different manner as well..)